# dropdown menu doesn't work in katana yootheme joomla template

Tags: templates, joomla, menu

I have tried everything but I can't get the dropdown menu to work with yootheme katana template for joomla 2.5. Everything is set up right in module preferences, and the menus work fine with other yootheme temlpates. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You've purchased a template from Yootheme, therefore you're entitled to their support, so please post a comment on their support page.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask them for support and let them check your site, but there is a small hack that worked for me several times while Joomla 3 was recently launched.
Go to your Joomla Administration Panel --> Extensions --> Module Manager, then click on your Main Menu or the menu that is having trouble, when it is opened go to Advanced, look for Menu Class Suffix and add this text "nav-pills" or in some cases leave a blank space before " nav-pills". See if that helps